# Can't access anything through GUI after killlall Xorg Command

Tags: xorg

I was having issues with my display resolution. It's stuck at 1024X768. Last Night it was okay(1080p). So when finding solutions, there was a step where I've to execute

```
sudo killlall Xorg
```

After this, the monitor blacked out & [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZJeX.jpg) screen came. After entering password, the same screen came. (This happens all the time when I run tat command.)

So, I restarted The PC, & [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgJQ4.jpg) odd desktop appeared where the top bar is white, there's no app or, software, Can't access start menu by pressing windows key, can't get to the side panel. but everything is accessible through the terminal.

Please tell me how can I fix it.

I tried reinstalling Xorg. Still same

Edit:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04(.01) LTS

Comment: Every other problem related to Resolution is now solved(by installing graphics driver), but other issues are still here.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely looks like you're having an issue with your graphics driver. Try `$ xrandr --verbose` on your shell to see all the available modes,
you then can use: `xrandr --ouput DVI-1 --mode 36000x1080` (if this shows up under --verbose, also mind that you may need tochange `DVI-1` to match your video output port)

Comment: Yes, the resolution issue was caused by driver. A clean install solved it. But the other issues are still there...

Answer (score 0):

Well, after fiddling around for hours, I found a way around, not a solution. I reinstalled the Gnome Launcher. But the top panel is still white, the left default panel is gone & found no way to bring it back. I still can't access the panel menu(windows key doesn't work).

It looks like, something is damaged, but I've no problem using it like this.